# Can I get text wrapping with "Through" to completely surround an irregular shape?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm trying to get text to wrap around an irregular shape using the "Through" text wrapping option, but it can't seem to fill in space between two parts of the image sticking out of the bottom.

Imagine a picture of a man with his arms raised up and his legs spread. The text fills in fine between his raised arms, but not between his spread legs.

I've edited the wrap points on the image so that they closely match the outline I'm going for, but the text won't fill in gaps underneath.

Do you have any idea how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved.  It turns out the points I'd been editing were the image points, and not the wrap points.  Editing the wrap points did the trick.